# Remove a relation in a manytomany list with jpa repository

Tags: java, jpa, repository, many-to-many, join

I am trying to setup a many to many relation between two classes, Account and Topic in my specific case. When a relation is added the corresponding table in the database looks fine but when a relation is to be removed(keeping both objects) nothing happens, the relation table looks exactly the same.

Topic:

```
@Entity(name = "topic")
public class Topic implements Serializable{
    .
    .
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "account_topic", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "topicId") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "accountId") })
    private List<Account> followers;
    .
    Getters and setters
    .
}
```

Account:

```
@Entity(name = "account")
public class Account implements Serializable {
    .
    .
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "account_topic", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "accountId") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "topicId") })
    private List<Topic> topics;
    .
    Getters and setters
    .
}
```

Failed attempt at removing relation:

```
@Autowired
private AccountRepository accountRepository;

@Autowired
private TopicRepository topicRepository;

public void removeTopicFromAccount(Long id, Long topicId) {
    Account account = accountRepository.findOne(id);
    Topic topic = topicRepository.findOne(topicId);
    account.getTopics().remove(topic);
    topic.getFollowers().remove(account);
    topicRepository.save(topic);
    accountRepository.save(account);
}
```

Thanks in advance for the taking the time to help me!

Comment: Whoever helps me solve the problem will get 1k DOGE-coins!!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your annotations to:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure why, but also 'FetchType.EAGER' seems wrong for bidirectional relationship... Should be LAZY really.